# Fontawesome Icon renders more than once after Array sort and display with Svelte #each

Tags: font-awesome, svelte, sapper

So I have a Sapper project where I use Fontawesome as front end Icon pack. I have an array displayed with svelte `#each` and in the html there is an icon and if I resort the array the position of the elements changes how it should be but now the Icons are rendered more than once next to each other. I think I know why it could be budged but I don't have a clue how to fix it. I think it's that the svelte renderer renders the component again and the fontawesome script just gets the info to render it again.

```html
<script>
  import { projectsFilter } from "@lib/store";

  export let item;
  let colapsed = true;

  projectsFilter.subscribe(filter => {
    colapsed = colapsed;
  });

  function changeState() {
    colapsed = !colapsed;
  }
</script>

<style type="text/scss">

</style>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-16by9">
      <img src={item.data.background} alt="placeholder" />
    </figure>
  </div>
  <header class="card-header">
    <p class="card-header-title">{item.data.name}</p>
    <button class="card-header-icon" on:click={changeState}>
      {#if !colapsed}
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true" />
        </span>
      {:else}
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true" />
        </span>
      {/if}
    </button>
  </header>
  {#if !colapsed}
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec
        iaculis mauris.
      </div>
    </div>
  {/if}
  <footer class="card-footer">
    <a href="./" class="card-footer-item">Save</a>
    <a href="./" class="card-footer-item">Edit</a>
    <a href="./" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

This is the component that's been rendered. Within the `#each` loop.

[The Arrows/angles are the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j5kN.png)

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Please provide a working example using [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-svelte).

Comment: Also it would be more interesting to see the portion where the `each` loop is located and where you manipulate the array you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code and check

```html
  <i class={!colapsed ? 'fas fa-angle-down' : 'fas fa-angle-up'}
          aria-hidden="true" />
```

and the whole code below

```html
<script>
  import { projectsFilter } from "@lib/store";

  export let item;
  let colapsed = true;

  projectsFilter.subscribe(filter => {
    colapsed = colapsed;
  });

  function changeState() {
    colapsed = !colapsed;
  }
</script>

<style type="text/scss">

</style>
 
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image" />
  <header class="card-header">
    <p class="card-header-title">asdads</p>
    <button class="card-header-icon" on:click={changeState}>
      <span class="icon">
        <i
          class={!colapsed ? 'fas fa-angle-down' : 'fas fa-angle-up'}
          aria-hidden="true" />
      </span>
    </button>
  </header>
  {#if !colapsed}
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec
        iaculis mauris.
      </div>
    </div>
  {/if}
  <footer class="card-footer">
    <a href="./" class="card-footer-item">Save</a>
    <a href="./" class="card-footer-item">Edit</a>
    <a href="./" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried exactly that but the Angle does not reload after I switch the collapsed variable so it stays in the collapsed position and I don't know why normally I use your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to preload both icons and switch the visibility with `aria-hidden=true` and `aria-hidden=false`.

I usually create my own css-classes and add and remove them in a toggle function:

```
.hidden {
    display = none;
  }

.shown {
    display = block;
  }
```

You can e.g. toggle with two functions like this:

```
function toggleCollapsed(event) {  // event.target might be a better way to catch the element...
    document.getElementById('ELEMENT1_ID').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.getElementById('ELEMENT1_ID').classList.add('shown');
    document.getElementById('ELEMENT2_ID').classList.remove('shown');
    document.getElementById('ELEMENT2_ID').classList.add('hidden');
}

function toggleFolded(event) {
    document.getElementById('ELEMENT1_ID').classList.remove('shown');
    document.getElementById('ELEMENT1_ID').classList.add('hidden');
    document.getElementById('ELEMENT2_ID').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.getElementById('ELEMENT2_ID').classList.add('shown');
}
```

Than you can e.g.:

```
<button class="card-header-icon" on:click={changeState === true ? toggleFolded : toggleCollapsed}>
```